# Need 3 time Vibration when notification comes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

When application is in background or not running and notification comes I want to vibrate iPhone for 3 time continuous or change pattern of vibration

I do the code when application is in running mode and notification come at that time I used `NSTimer` and used below code for vibrate.

```
 AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

But not working when application in background and application is closed.

If anybody have any idea then please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

As `NSTimer` will not work in background so while app is in background its not calling your methods of vibrate device.

**Here is one alternate work around to vibrate device without timer.**

```
//Call Your method like this 
    self.vibrateCount = 0;
    [self vibrateDevice];

-(void)vibrateDevice{
    NSLog(@"Device Vibrate");
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithCompletion(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate, ^{
        AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    });
    self.vibrateCount++;

    if (self.vibrateCount<3) {
//        [self performSelector:@selector(vibrateDevice) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSTimer* t = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self  selector:@selector(vibrateDevice) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:t forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
        });
    }
}
```

This will work in background app mode but you have only limited time **(approx 10 sec only)** to call this while you got notification so be careful to call it.

Hope this will work!

Comment: thanks for your answer but when application is not running at that time we don't use this code. Even application is also not know weather notification comes or not until user click on notification

Comment: Yes Mahesh before `iOS 10` we can not handle this but now in `iOS 10` we can handle this push notification without user click please check iOS 10 feature of APNS

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void){            AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

It just simply doesn't work.
My APNS payload is

```
{
    "aps":{
        "alert":"YOUR MESSAGE",
        "content-available" : 1
    }
}
```

And also, I have tried UNNotificationServiceExtension. I tried

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
}
```

It doesn't work either. So I think it's impossible to vibrate multiple times on receive remote push in background.